# Can we take a position *against* the moderator strike?

Tags: discussion, support, display-names

I've been previously banned for stating,

- "I stand against Israeli apartheid"

And for having the nickname "Israel is an apartheid state", I've reviewed the merits of this strike, and I stand against it too.

Can I use the name *"Evan Carroll against mod strike"* on Stack Exchange, or is that also bannable? I see a lot of moderators using their names to articulate their status with the strike.

---

I'm not sure why this matters, but because people think it's impossible to get banned for your username... as seen [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390495/can-we-take-a-position-against-the-moderator-strike#comment1304258_390495) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390497/157251) and want to make this question about that..

> You have (at least on MSE) never been suspended solely for your username. [...] - Tinkeringbell Mod

[image: here i got banned..]

Also, there was no bigotry. It's not bigotry to call South Africa or any state "apartheid". That's a political position against a state policy, and you can't be a bigot against a nation.

Comment: It brings up a perfectly valid point about censorship and free speech (I'm not referring to the more sensitive issue regarding apartheid which is a separate headache for the PR department). Personally, I'd be more interested in hearing your argument against it if posted in one of the existing threads related to the topic. Just my view.

Comment: Then again...considering your vast history of prior posts complaining about moderator actions, wouldn't you support a reduction in moderation activity on the sites, resulting from the strike?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I would! Go on?

Comment: You're no stranger to suspensions and, in fact, you seem to strive for them. So, why ask here? Why not just change your username and see what happens? Because you're a troll.

Comment: @Stuckat1337 because I've been banned on the network for changing my username. And, this is the site to open `[discussions|` on policy, and seek to `[support]` on policy questions.

Comment: Can you show some evidence of being banned _only_ for changing your username? Or are you perhaps telling just a selective portion of the truth?

Comment: @Stuckat1337 satisfied? bet not,

Comment: Did you even read the whole message? Bet not?

Answer (score 56):

You have (at least on MSE) *never* been suspended *solely* for your username. You've been suspended several times for the behavior that goes with it, using your username to antagonize other users and using it as a pretext to start discussions with/about them that then turn harsh *is* unfriendly.

Then again, I don't see much difference in your behavior whether your name is Evan or something else, so by all means, go ahead.

Comment: I don't agree with those summaries of past events, but I'm guessing the behavior that you think warrants removal is merely defending yourself. But regardless, I'm really glad to see another Mod that hasn't gone on strike, and that doesn't stand with the strikers. So props to you.

Comment: @Evan you probably "forgot" personal insults you threw at me in comments, or even posts. Those are the actions that warrant suspension.

Comment: Can't think of one time in my whole life where I ever insulted anyone. Feel free to paste the screencap here, or link it here, or email me at me@evancarroll.com so at least i know what you're talking about.

Comment: "...see another Mod that hasn't gone on strike, and that doesn't stand with the strikers." Just because a moderator hasn't gone on strike, doesn't mean they don't stand with the strikers.

Comment: @ouflak I am not on strike. I always assume the best, per site rules.

Comment: @EvanCarroll, I took a peek at your site accounts. I didn't see a diamond beside your name on any of them, so I assumed you were just generally implying that any moderator who has not gone on strike does not support the strike. But that's not necessarily true.

Comment: You're correct on both assumptions. This seldom happens. I hope you stay around, you have tremendous potential: I am not a moderator. And, I am implying that moderators not on strike do not support the strike. The whole purpose of a strike is work stoppage. You can't support that cause when you're giving material aid to the production process.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell can i update your answer with a formal response? if ok with you, I'd love to respond to you in the answer.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Please don't. You know how these sites work and you know that an answer isn't a place for a conversation. Stop being a heel.

Comment: @Stuckat1337 ok, so where would you like me to challange the claim that i've never been "solely" suspended for my username? If this was my answer, and I was using it to spread a fabrication about someone, I would welcome them to respond to it inline.

Comment: @EvanCarroll I don't really care. But an argument doesn't belong in someone else's answer, and you are very well aware of that.

Comment: @Stuckat1337 i'm not aware of that. I welcome people to add context to my answers, and I would hope others would do the same. However, I don't think it is acceptable to tell other people what they're aware of and generally be patronizing. but feel free to check the question for your context.

Comment: @EvanCarroll What you're willing to do or allow doesn't necessarily match with the expectations of other users on this site. If I wrote a technical answer you didn't agree with, I certainly wouldn't expect you to vandalize my answer by starting an argument with me _within the answer_.

Comment: @Stuckat1337 if my answer was technically incorrect, i would welcome you to edit it. but i could just be less emotional about my answers

Comment: @EvanCarroll I didn't say _incorrect_. If you had a typo, sure, I might fix it. But I'm much more likely to point it out to you in a comment. If I didn't like the approach you were taking, or didn't agree that it would solve the OP's problem, trying to force you to engage in a debate _in your answer_ is offensive and just completely anti-social behavior.

Comment: @EvanCarroll , "The whole purpose of a strike is work stoppage." No it isn't. And it is strange that someone posting about standing against the moderation strike wouldn't know what the purpose of the strike is. There are many posts about it. Both sides have made public statements. If you disagree with one side or the other on either of their stances or the actions they've taken as a result of those stances, fair enough. Since you've created this topic, why not take the opportunity to defend StackExchange's positions from a user's perspective? It might actually yield some thoughtful debate.

Comment: I was a card carrying union member for years. Just look it up, "Strike action, also called labor strike, labour strike, or simply strike, is a **work stoppage** caused by the mass refusal of employees to work." That's just a the most basic definition ever. It's tactic to stop work, to bring pressure on those who are interested in seeing work continue. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strike_action This is also why one person doesn't go on strike. You have to be able to impact production to be a strike. Otherwise you're just taking time off.

Comment: And, I've already defended StackExcahage's position. StackExchnge has taken a position that has caused moderators to rage quit without merit, merely because they told them what they _couldn't say_. The same reason the mods rage quit last time when they were told they couldn't say/harass transpeople with arbitrary pronouns. Now they can't say they're removing content or banning because it's LLM-generated, though they can still ban people and delete content. This is fantastic, **mods on strike for mere rhetorical constraints? This makes the network better for everyone.**

Comment: @EvanCarroll, I must say that after reading these comments and your original post, that it's not clear to me that you understand either StackExchange's position or the moderator's position. I don't doubt that you sincerely care... but about what - I have no idea.

Answer (score 21):

Just continuing to use the network as you always have and not signing the open letter is arguably taking a position against the strike. It's the online version of crossing the picket line.

Also posting here on Meta that you're against the strike takes a position against it. So, you're done! You've successfully taken a position against the strike.

Answer (score 18):

I doubt the company would object to you supporting them, and I believe the vast majority of moderators respect freedom of speech and would not censor a viewpoint that was not stated offensively. I would expect the company to override them if they did.

Comment: Do you think it's offensive to merely state "Israel is an Apartheid State"?

Comment: @EvanCarroll Not particularly, but it definitely depends on how you say it and where. A quick google search and I found questions on [politics stackexchange](https://politics.stackexchange.com) that discuss [Why do some lecturers consider Israel to be an "apartheid" country?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/3009). If you posted your question on MSE it will get closed as off-topic, and if your question contained hate then you will rightfully be banned.

Comment: @EvanCarroll worth noting, I stand in full support of Palestinians, but that does not give me the right to say anything hurtful or post off-topic questions. Of course, I'm only speculating here, I haven't seen your (now deleted) post about that topic

Comment: No hate just respectfully calling into question a corporate policy and specifying why it's relevant with an example https://web.archive.org/web/20210518054035/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364543/antizionism-and-antisemitism-are-different-we-should-not-confuse-the-two-when-m or with typos fixed (deleted link) https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364543/157251

Comment: @EvanCarroll thanks for providing the archive. I would be happy to discuss my opinion about the post and the linked chatroom, but I think that's very out of the scope of this post and especially this answer. Perhaps opening a chatroom to discuss would be more appropriate? I personally haven't used them before so idk how it works. But we should definitely not continue the discussion here

Comment: @EvanCarroll no hate speech? Pity I didn't take screenshots. You are very like ChatGPT, telling lies as if it's the truth, and maybe even believing it, while totally oblivious to reality. Really a pity because you appear to be a smart person.

Comment: See I never once insulted you. You have no evidence. I've been nice to you the whole time. You were mean in this post saying comparing me to chat GPT. And you're a "moderator" and what I mean that is you're a fairly inactive user who comes here not to participate but to moderate: your last contribution was in 2021? https://stackexchange.com/users/201110/shadow-wizard-chasing-stars?tab=activity Why are you so passionate about the way this site is run, when you clearly not an active participant in the main Q/A functionality?

Comment: Being passive aggressive, condescending, patronising, spurious, etc, are all insults in my book. If you pulled this crap on a site where I was a mod, and I wasn’t on strike (go team!), you’d have been booted out ages ago. This isn’t a court of law, burden of evidence is not the same here. Disruptive influences need the shoe treatment.

Comment: there ya go, that's why i stand against the mod strike. a bunch of people taking actions regardless of rules because they think it's undesirable or disruptive. network is better for this strike. hope it goes on FOREVER. I'm for rules, transparency, and discourse. Not your opinion of "disruption".

Comment: Is it possible to disable notifications for comments on your own post?

Comment: @Someone-OnStrike No, but if you have an ad-blocker / CSS userstyle extension, you can add a rule like `.inbox-item[relatedpostid="390496"] { display: none; }` as a workaround.